# Core Data + swift Int = crash

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In my model, I've an object `Object` with an attribute `attribute` with type `Int`.

Here is the Object.swift file:

```
class Object: NSManagedObject {
  @NSManaged var attribute: Int
}
```

and here is where I use it:

```
let anInt: Int = 3
security.attribute = anInt
```

The code works fine on 64-bit devices, but on 32-bit devices, it crashes because of the unrecognized selector `Object.attribute`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to mark the attribute as `Int64` in the `NSManagedObject` object

```
class Object: NSManagedObject {
  @NSManaged var attribute: Int64
}
```

and cast the `Int` to `Int64`

```
let anInt: Int = 3
security.attribute = Int64(anInt)
```

Comment: Right, because Core Data doesn't have an `Int` type, it has several integer types that all have specific sizes.